# What should I do about the Heartbleed bug for the sites I run?

Tags: openssl, heartbleed

The recently announced Heartbleed bug in OpenSSL affects many sites (70% of the internet).

There's a website:

http://www.heartbleed.com

There's a web-based test:

http://filippo.io/Heartbleed/

What should I do to protect the sites that I run?

Comment: Better answered on [sf] - [Heartbleed: What is it and what are options to mitigate it?](http://serverfault.com/q/587329)

Comment: … as well as the StackExchange for security professionals.  See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55076/ and http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heartbleed .

Comment: Every major SE computer related site now has this question... Probably soon it will be asked even on [cooking.stackexchange.com](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/) :D

Comment: I have added an end-user version of this question at http://superuser.com/questions/739260/what-should-end-users-do-about-the-heartbleed-security-bug (but someone has already downvoted it, without explanation).

Comment: @Nikolay, now I'm so tempted to ask it on cooking.se...

Answer (score 7):

You should:

- Update your system to the latest OpenSSL version
- Generate new keys and certificates for services relying on OpenSSL and restart them
- Revoke former certificates
- Invalidate all established sessions

Comment: I don’t suppose you know of some nice clear instructions for the last three steps, do you?

Comment: Revoking and regenerating production certificates usually involves whichever process your CA has in place. Since that varies from one CA to the next...

Comment: How to update your system depends on your package manager. Invalidating sessions is application-dependent. As for certificates, you'll have to contact your CA but the first step should be to generate a new key and CSR: `openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout post_heartbleed.key -out post_heartbleed.csr`!

Answer (score 4):

[Stolen from a reddit comment.](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/22ghj1/the_heartbleed_bug/cgmzjg1)

1. Update your system:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
2. Reboot the server
3. `openssl version -a` to make sure you have the latest version!!

Comment: The OP delivers!

Comment: @IamJohnGalt It's not like it's a locked safe or something. ;)

Comment: This is **not** sufficient. The SSL keys need to be replaced, without doing that a patch will still leave you vulnerable to past key theft.

Comment: This assumes your system uses `apt-get` as your package manager. The question does not suggest this is necessarily the case.

Answer (score 0):

More specifically for Ubuntu or Debian in general

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 stop
aptitude update
dpkg -l \*libssl\*
aptitude safe-upgrade libssl1.0.0
dpkg -l \*libssl\*
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

Ref  http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2165-1/